# Convert Object to Array returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, jsx

Here is the object I'm trying to convert into array:

```
{ 1: {..}, 2: {..}, 3: {..}, 4: {..}, 5: {..}}
```

This is the function I'm using to convert the Object into array:

```
const convertObjectToArray = (object) => {
  const array = [];

  if (object) {
    Object.keys(object).forEach((key) => {
      array.push({[key]: object[key]});
    })
    console.log('object inside function', object);
    console.log('array inside function', array);
    return array;
  } else {
    return [];
  }
}
```

And here the render method:

```
class PostList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { postList } = this.props;

    const array = convertObjectToArray(postList);

    console.log('postList', postList);
    console.log('array', array);

    return (
      <div>
        {array.map(({ id, ...otherCollectionProps }) => {
          return (
            <Post key={id} {...otherCollectionProps} />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

The problem here is that I get the error of "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined", when inside the console I get logged the array with values - and so I don't understand how I get the undefined value

[These are the objects/arrays I get logged into console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNCaa.png)
I have tried following these other issues:
 1. [Object to Array returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50787605/object-to-array-returns-undefined)
 2. [Mapping Object to convert object to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44615552/mapping-object-to-convert-object-to-array)

But they were not useful enough to get this issue fixed

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: Try using a different variable name besides 'array'.

Comment: Just tried but it doesn't change

Comment: Is this your entire code? I see no reason why ```array``` would be undefined.

Comment: Try use method Array.from() to covert object to array. Here is the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/from

Comment: No that's not my entire code; I fixed anyway the issue following Dennis Vash's answer. Thanks everyone for trying help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) **which returns an array of object's values**.

```js
const object = { 1: { a: 'a'}, 2: { b: 'b'}, 3: { c: 'c'} }
const convertObjectToArray = Object.values;

console.log(convertObjectToArray(object));
```

Comment: Tried it and it actually works, thanks a lot!! For avoiding future issues like this one, do you know why I was getting an undefined value with the previous code?

Comment: Can't find a mistake on those snippets, it should come from some other place